# Material UI Tooltip Stays Open after triggered Dialog is closed

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

My assumption is the state of the Dialog is causing the issue, but I have not been able to figure this out. The Tooltip works as intended until the IconButton is clicked. The Dialog pops up as it should but when the dialog is exited, the Tooltip pops up as active.

```
class DeleteDocument extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  onDeleteFile() {
    try {
      ensureJobIsUnlocked();
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }

    const confirmedByUser = true;
    if (confirmedByUser) {
      this.props.onDeleteFile(this.props.selectedDocument.id);
      this.setState({ open: false });
    }
  }

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tooltip id="tooltip-icon" title="Delete Document">
          <div>
            <IconButton
              disabled={(this.props.selectedDocument == null)}
              onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
            >
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Tooltip>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{'Delete Document'}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
              This will delete the currently active PDF/Component Design. Are you sure you want to do this?
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.onDeleteFile.bind(this)} color="primary" autoFocus>
              Delete
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried out your code and I'm getting the same thing... I found an issue on the material-ui github page that looks to be similar behavior.  https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11186 I think it's just a bug in the library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See issue [#9624](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9624):

> This is the expected behavior. It's done for accessibility considerations. You have two options, either disable the tooltip response to focus events or disable the dialog restore focus behavior.

**1. Disable the tooltip response to focus events** ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#props))

```js
<Tooltip disableTriggerFocus={true} />
```

[image: Edit Material-ui - tooltip disable restore focus trigger]

**2. Disable the dialog restore focus behavior** ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props))

```js
<Dialog disableRestoreFocus={true} />
```

[image: Edit Material-ui - tooltip disable restore focus]

Comment: It's flagged up at the start but worth repeating: this behaviour is deliberate and important to some users. Please do not tinker with it unless you massively understand what you're doing or else you will very probably make your app unusable for people with disabilities. If I've tabbed all the way through a large UI to get to this button, and then it loses focus and I have to do it again, I will be far more cross than if I have to look at a tooltip.

Comment: Second option worked for me. Although I will consider not disabling now that I know why it works this way.

Comment: Note that in react you don't need to set it to true like`disableRestoreFocus={true}` but just do `disableRestoreFocus`.  The `={true}` is implied if not given

Answer (score 9):

set `disableFocusListener={true}` according to this doc https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/